# auth email in laravel template and vue component for display and data passing

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can access my logged in users email address in a way that I can display it in my template but also have it accessible in an axios call upon a form submission.

I'm using vue with laravel 5.8 and trying to do this with the blade and component

blade

```
<test-component :email="{{ Auth::user()->email }}"></test-component>
```

test.vue

```
<template>
<div>

    <div>
        Creator - <span> {{ email }} </span>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

... 


props: [
    email: ''
]
```

How can I properly store the email to both be displayed and passed in axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing `Auth::user()->email` through the prop, like this`:email="{{ Auth::user()->email }}"` - you are able to use `this.email` in your `vue` component to access it, and send it through `axios` simple as this:

```js
axios.post('/user', {
    email: this.email,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Also, if you want to have your `auth` user always available in your `vue` component you can do it by assigning it to `window.user` variable like this:

```html
<script> window.user = {{ Auth::user() }}</script>
```

Then in your `vue` component you can do something like this `window.user.email` and such.

Also, I encourage you to take a look at [this article](https://dev.to/aschmelyun/four-ways-to-pass-data-from-laravel-to-vue-5d8m) - it will give you some more examples.

Hope this helps.